# how do you access an array that has elements from firebase in the global scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i tried accessing the array of elements from firebase and it returns an empty array maybe its because firebase takes time to load the data but the code would be already done if i try to put the array in fetch function the add to cart will will not be able to access the array here is code

```js
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var productsRef = firebase.database().ref("products");

// Fetch products from Firebase
var products = [];
// Fetch products from Firebase
productsRef.once("value")
.then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var product = childSnapshot.val();
        products.push({
            id: childSnapshot.key,
            name: product.name,
            img: product.imageUrl,
            description: product.description,
            price: product.price,
            category: product.category
        });
    });
    console.log(categories); 
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error fetching products: " + error);
});

let i = 0;
const categories = [...new Set(products.map((item)=>{return item}))]//`**EMPTY ARRAY**`

document.getElementById('product-container').innerHTML = categories.map((item)=>{
    var {img, name,description, price} = item;
    return(
        `<div class='box'>
            <div class='picDiv'>
                <img class='images' src=${img}></img>
            </div>
           <div class='bottom'>
                <h2>$ ${name}.00</h2>
                <p>${price}</p>
                <p>${description}</p>`+
                "<button onclick='addtocart("+(i++)+")'>Add to cart</button>"+
            `</div>
        </div>`
    )
}).join('');
let cart = [];

function addtocart(a){
    cart.push(...categories[a]);
    displaycart();
}
function deleteCart(a){
    cart.splice(a, 1);
    displayProducts();
}

function displaycart(){
    let j = 0, total=0;
    //document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=cart.length;
    if(cart.length==0){
        //document.getElementById('cartItem').innerHTML = "Your cart is empty";
        //document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "$ "+0+".00";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("cartItem").innerHTML = cart.map((items)=>{
            var {img, name,description, price} = items;
            total=total+price;
            //document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "$ "+total+".00";
            return(
                `<div class='cart-item'>
                    <div class='cart-img'>
                        <img class='images' src=${img}></img>
                    </div>
                   <div class='bottom'>
                        <h2 style='font-size:16px;'> ${name}</h2>
                        <p style='font-size: 12px;'>$ ${price}</p>
                        <p style='font-size: 12px;'>${description}</p>`+
                        "<i class='fa-solid fa-trash' onclick='deleteCart("+ (j++) +")'></i></div>"+
                    `</div>
                </div>`
            )
        }).join('');
    }  
}
```

this is the code its not showing any results its saying the categories is empty.

Comment: "*maybe its because firebase takes time to load the data*" - yes, that's exactly it. You need to use a useEffect hook for anything that runs asynchronously and returns a promise that later resolves with the actual data.

Comment: For an example of this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65634000/display-data-in-react-native-component-firebase/65634302#65634302 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71940869/results-from-realtime-db-not-available-when-called/71941122#71941122